# Lock-free atomic update to immutable Map

Tags: java, immutability, atomic, vavr

Given a Javaslang / Vavr [immutable map](http://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.0/io/vavr/collection/Map.html), and a function that updates that map:

```
private Map<Foo, Bar> myMap = HashMap.empty();

public void setBar(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
  myMap = myMap.put(foo, bar);
}
```

How can I ensure that two concurrent calls to `setBar()` for different `Foo` keys will both have their updates recorded?

```
// thread A
setBar(fooA, barA)

// thread B
setBar(fooB, barB)
```

It seems like there's a risk that the calls will be interleaved such that:

1. thread A gets `{}`
2. thread B gets `{}`
3. thread B computes `{}` + `fooB -> barB` = `{(fooB -> barB)}`
4. thread B sets `myMap` to `{(fooB -> barB)}`
5. thread A computes `{}` + `fooA -> barA` = `{(fooA -> barA)}`
6. thread A sets `myMap` to `{(fooA -> barA)}`
7. thread B's update is lost

Using `AtomicReference`, I came up with the following, more or less based on the `ConcurrentStack` methods in the “Nonblocking Algorithms” section of [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/).

```
private AtomicReference<Map<Foo, Bar>> myMap = 
  new AtomicReference<>(HashMap.empty());

public void setBar(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
  Map<Foo, Bar> myMap0;
  Map<Foo, Bar> myMap1;
  do {
    myMap0 = myMap.get();
    myMap1 = myMap0.put(foo, bar);
  } while (!myMap.compareAndSet(myMap0, myMap1));
}
```

Is this correct? And if so, is it as good an implementation as I'm likely to get, or is there something simpler (e.g. some Java 8 `AtomicReference` API I'm missing that implements this pattern)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `AtomicReference` is good in this case. You can use the shortcut method

```
public void setBar(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    myMap.updateAndGet(map -> map.put(foo, bar)));
}
```

instead. See the [javadoc for `AtomicReference.updateAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#updateAndGet-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-). The default java implementation is exactly the same as yours in Java 8.