# What is an idiomatic way to use AtomicReference while using a Map in vavr?

Tags: java, functional-programming, immutability, vavr

This is more of a question that inquires what is the approach preferred by seasoned hands in Stack OverFlow community. I want to learn about that because I don't want to write unnecessary boilerplate code. So, treat my Q as that of a newbie's.

My query is taking a cue from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147719/lock-free-atomic-update-to-immutable-map) and the answers on SOF. @[Nandor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2699901/n%C3%A1ndor-el%C5%91d-fekete) has clarified that AtomicReference is the way to go.

In a typical application, where a class uses a Map to store some data, updates to this Map are almost always required. I am using Vavr's HashMap implementation for the purpose. Needless to say, I am going for *Immutability* here.

The problem I am working on is simulated here, using a fictitious *CourierSlottingMachine*. It holds a map that associates an agent and the bag (perhaps a collection but we don't know because that's encapsulated) that this agent has to carry. Let's assume that folks from front-office can *only add* a new agent and her bag to the machine.

```
public class CourierSlottingMachine {

    private Map<AgentID, BagOfDeliveryItems>   allAgents;
    // ... other members, suitable constructor and methods
   
    public CourierDesk hereComesAnAgent(AgentID agentID,BagOfDeliveryItems bag) {

       // Two front-office clerks (== two threads) add two agents
       this.allAgents = this.allAgents.put(agentID,bag); // We don't mind overwriting the old bag
       return (this); 
      
    }
}
```

What I understand is that the 'put' function works on principle of immutability.
From Vavr's Map API, the `put(K,V)`:

> Returns: A new Map containing these elements and that entry.

Therefore, clerk(1) adds her agent and stores the new resultant Map to `this.allAgents`. So, does clerk(2). It is then possible (not always) that when the function returns with `this`, only one clerk's addition is visible to the external world.
In other words, it is possible that one of front office clerks, may find later on, that the agent (and the bag) she added was missing from the slotting machine (`this`).

The solution to this, again by my understanding, is that `CourierSlottingMachine` should hold an *AtomicRefence* to the Map of `allAgents`, instead of just a reference to it, like so:

```
public class CourierSlottingMachine {

    private AtomicReference<Map<AgentID, BagOfDeliveryItems>>   allAgents;
    // ... other members, suitable constructor and methods
   
    public CourierDesk hereComesAnAgent(AgentID agentID,BagOfDeliveryItems bag) {

       // Two front-office clerks (== two threads) add two agents
       this.allAgents = this.allAgents.updateAndGet(m -> m.put(agentID,bag)); 
       return (this); 
      
    }
}
```

I have three primary questions:

- Is my understanding correct?
- If so, then any class which has an updatable member variable, exposed to modification operations by multiple simultaneous threads, should always use an AtomicReference instead of just the Reference to that member variable: is this the pattern that we should always follow?
- If I am using a AtomicReference all the time, then do we really get any benefit of immutable collections offered by Vavr? This may be a very basic question, but I need to plug holes in my understanding, if any.

Comment: It likely depends on how you then use the map; but as it stands, this seems a lot more complicated than using a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: "`this.allAgents = this.allAgents.updateAndGet(...);`" isn't type-correct: `updateAndGet` returns the value of the `AtomicReference`, not the `AtomicReference`.

Comment: @AndyTurner : sincere apologies. I should have responded much earlier. Yes, that code is incorrect. I should have been careful while writing the snippet here. The original code doesn't have the mark of embarrassment. Moreover, the code that runs today indeed uses a ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

Well the understanding is correct, the code is a little bit off. You don't need to reassign `this.allAgents` (actually that's the whole point) - just the updateAndGet is enough, it operates on the same variable.

> ...should always use an AtomicReference instead of just the Reference to that member variable...

AtomicReference is just one of the ways, you can use locks, synchronization or other mechanisms. If performance really matters to you then you should consider other options - if you have really high contention (threads often fight for this variable) then locks will perform better than atomics. As far as patterns go, I would suggest a pattern of having your fields final - you are gonna avoid mistakes like that (overwriting a vavr list variable for example) thanks to final fields.

> then do we really get any benefit of immutable collections offered by Vavr?

You do benefit, it's a completely different thing, and it's really amazing actually. I'm bad at explaining, but let's go.

Imagine you have a table (your `CourierSlottingMachine` class) and there is a box (your `Map`) on that table. The box is protected by a guard (`AtomicReference`), so only one person can come and do something with it. The box itself is designed in a way that only one person can operate on it.

So do you really need a guard if the box is already protected? No. So in your case you basically do not benefit, could just use `ConcurrentHashMap`.

But now imagine that you let people take the box with them, wherever they want (returning the `Map` from your method). If one person takes your box, then he has his own copy, he can do whatever he wants with it - destroy it, cut it in half and make two boxes, whatever. Then the best part - if he wants the same box he had a couple minutes ago, he just comes in and takes it again. And other people can take it aswell and do whatever they want, and it's not gonna affect other peoples boxes. Why a guard then? Imagine you added something valuable to the box and you want your box to be on display right now - that's what the guard is for.

Now imagine a same case if the box wouldn't be a vavr box - it could but a normal java box, or even a concurrent java box. There is always only one box. People can take it, but they have to return it before anyone else is allowed to take it. No private boxes anymore, no copies, no safe point of return - someone else may even steal your items you put there before.

This analogy fell through halfway, but I hope it helps at least a little bit :)

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. Your explanation is more than sufficient :-). It served the purpose: to strengthen my understanding. To summarise: either I make an AtomicReference of that CourierSlottingMachine, 'private final' so that unintended assignment is prevented or, I use a ConcurrentHashMap and never let that reference sneak out to outsiders. Have I got you right?

Comment: Well yeah, basically. Final is not strictly necessary, just to avoid accidents, I always use it on fields as good practice.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I put a 'final' qualifier in front of a member variable of a non-POJO class by default and then let further understanding of the flow - as it emerges - override that decision, if needs be. Thanks, again.